# Pandoc markdown: Omit text in PDF version but include in HTML version

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to maintain two versions of my CV, one with lots of gloss and one that's more conventional.  The glossy version will be HTML.  I have it working with images (e.g. when I include an image using straight-up HTML code, Pandoc non-strict ignores the image and alt text in the PDF version but includes it in the HTML version.

However, for straight-up text, it's not working.  I've tried wrapping it in `<p>text</p>` or `<div>text</div>`, but the PDF version seems to be ignoring the code while leaving the text content intact.

Reproducible example:

```
**My CV**

Content to appear in both

<img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png' alt='image to only appear in HTML'>

<p>Text to only appear in HTML</p>
```

How do I flag text content so that it only appears in the HTML version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With recent versions of pandoc, you can disable the extension `markdown_in_html_blocks`:

```
pandoc -f markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks
```

Then the contents of `<div>...</div>` tags will be ignored in LaTeX/PDF output, but will still appear in HTML.

Comment: Thanks.  Updated pandoc in Ubuntu but it is still stuck at 1.10.1 so can't test.

Comment: This doesn't work in recent versions of pandoc.  This does however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083891/1175053