# Pandoc Markdown: ignore text in PDF (but include in HTML) Updated?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

This question of how to include text that will appear in html but not pdf has been answered twice ([LaTeX multicolumn block in Pandoc markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982836/latex-multicolumn-block-in-pandoc-markdown) and [Pandoc markdown: Omit text in PDF version but include in HTML version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812365/pandoc-markdown-omit-text-in-pdf-version-but-include-in-html-version)) and I applied the solution recommended:

Here is the source:

```
My text.

<div>
This will be ignored in non-HTML output
</div>

Other text
```

The command I used was:
`pandoc essai.md --from=markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks -o essai.pdf`

Yet the text between the `<div>`tags is still displayed in the pdf file.

Am I missing something obvious? Or has the behaviour of pandoc changed since 2013/2014 (my version is 1.19 of 2016)? If yes, what would the solution be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you asked for a solution that works with pandoc 1.19, but for completeness, here is one which is a bit cleaner but only works with pandoc 2.0 and later:

There is a new *raw_attribute* extension, which allows to do the following:

```
`text in html`{=html}
`text in pdf`{=latex}
```

It is enabled in pandoc markdown per default.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer: add the `-native_divs` extension.

This way:

```
$ pandoc essai.md --from=markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks-native_divs -t latex
My text.

other text
```

My understanding is that pandoc has started interpreting `<div>` items as "native" elements, i.e. represented in the AST, which causes the interesting side effect that a `<p>` is added in html. This behaviour needs to be deactivated in order to obtain the desired effect.

If someone has a better solution or a better explanation, please let me know.