# Pandoc: have either LaTeX or Markdown/HTML render, but not both?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

The example I have in mind is the trivial case of rendering the LaTeX logo using the `\LaTeX` command for PDF or similar output, and otherwise presenting just a "LaTeX" literal.

I've tried a few overly-clever quoting and commenting methods without luck.

For example:

```
Just print the
\LaTeX % LaTeX
logo.
```

... doesn't work.

Putting the `\LaTeX` command inside HTML comments `<!-- ... -->`, even across multiple lines, doesn't work:

```
Just print the
<!-- \LaTeX % --> LaTeX
logo.
```

Or:

```
Just print the <!--
\LaTeX % --> LaTeX
logo.
```

Just to make this more challenging, I'd actually prefer this to be in an unordered list:

```
* \LaTeX.
```

Other than specifically manipulating the source Markdown (say, a regex replacement of "\" with "\LaTeX"), before generating latex-based outputs, is there a way to do this within Markdown and Pandoc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandoc Markdown: ignore text in PDF (but include in HTML) Updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083724/pandoc-markdown-ignore-text-in-pdf-but-include-in-html-updated)

Comment: Thanks, that does it!

Answer (score 3):

The solution which works for me is to use the *raw attribute extension* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084040/9105048), for Pandoc 2.0 and later.

My bullet-item example renders as desired with:

```
 * `\LaTeX`{=latex} `LaTeX`{=html}.
```

In HTML I get "LaTeX".  In PDF, I get the styled LaTeX logo.